# User-Based Collaborative Filtering with sparse matrices Python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, collaborative-filtering

I'm implementing the Recommender System for a portal with 1 million(a month) unique users and 13000 items and I'm keen to do it great in terms of Big Data.

**# --- Start Item Based Recommendations with Sparse --- #**

```
data = pd.read_csv('.../.csv').astype(float)

def cosine_similarities(mat):
    col_normed_mat = pp.normalize(mat.tocsc(), axis=0)
    return col_normed_mat.T * col_normed_mat

data_germany = data.drop('user', 1)
data = csc_matrix(data)
data_germany = csr_matrix(data_germany)
csc = cosine_similarities(data_germany)
csc = csc.tocoo(copy=False)

csc.data
Out[74]:
array([ 0.02988072,  0.01698824,  0.0174342 , ...,  0.03207501,
        0.09016696,  0.06804138])
```

Having Cosine Distance in my sparse matrix I can use all my items and get by row/col the data to advise it. That's simple one.

The question is how to do and implement User-Based CF with Sparse Matrices. SciPy Matrices are so bad in terms of diversity of existing methods. The methods doesn't allow me fully write code for doing User-Based CF with Sparse Matrices. I want to get the same affect for my CF but with Sparse Matrix.

**# --- Start User Based Recommendations with **no** Sparse --- #**

```
# Helper function to get similarity scores
def getScore(history, similarities):
   return sum(history*similarities)/sum(similarities)

# Create a place holder matrix for similarities, and fill in the user name column
data_sims = pd.DataFrame(index=data.index,columns=data.columns)
data_sims.ix[:,:1] = data.ix[:,:1]

#Loop through all rows, skip the user column, and fill with similarity scores
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
    for j in range(1,len(data_sims.columns)):
        user = data_sims.index[i]
        product = data_sims.columns[j]

        if data.ix[i][j] == 1:
            data_sims.ix[i][j] = 0
        else:
            product_top_names = data_neighbours.ix[product][1:10]
            product_top_sims = data_ibs.ix[product].order(ascending=False)[1:10]
            user_purchases = data_germany.ix[user,product_top_names]

            data_sims.ix[i][j] = getScore(user_purchases,product_top_sims)

# Get the top songs
data_recommend = pd.DataFrame(index=data_sims.index, columns=['user','1','2','3','4','5','6'])
data_recommend.ix[0:,0] = data_sims.ix[:,0]

# Instead of top song scores, we want to see names
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
    data_recommend.ix[i,1:] = data_sims.ix[i,:].order(ascending=False).ix[1:7,].index.transpose()

# Print a sample
print data_recommend.ix[:10,:4]
```